# Setting Selenium RC speed via command line

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc

I'm using SeleniumRC to run some selense tests via command line. This works mostly fine, but some tests are failing because the execution speed is too high. How can I set the test runner's default execution speed?

The command I am using the run the test suite is

> java -jar
>   selenium-rc\selenium-server-1.0.3\selenium-server.jar
>   -port 5561 -htmlSuite "*firefox" "{myrootpath}" "{pathtomytestsuite}"
>   "{pathtoresults}"

Thanks for your help,

Adrian

Comment: Is adding a setSpeed command to the beginning of the test an option?

Comment: Nah, that would be too easy, where's the fun in this? Ok, seriously, I completely missed this one. Thanks a lot! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As  fiirhok kindly pointed out, the solution is simply to add setSpeed at the beginning of the test. I can't believe I missed this...